# How does requests determine the encoding of a reponse?

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-requests

How can a response's `apparent_encoding` attribute be incorrect?

I have the below code snippet, demonstrates my question:

```
import requests

url = "https://item.jd.com/100000177760.html"

r = requests.get(url)

print(r.status_code, r.encoding)  # 200, gbk (correct)

print(r.apparent_encoding)  # GB2312 (wrong)
```

How does requests determine the response's characters encoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requests [extracts](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/3e7d0a873f838e0001f7ac69b1987147128a7b5f/requests/utils.py#L480) the encoding from the response's Content-Type header's `charset` parameter.  If no `charset` is found in the header and the content-type is of type "text", ISO-8859-1 (latin-1) is assumed.  Otherwise the response's `apparent_encoding` property is [evaluated](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/428f7a275914f60a8f1e76a7d69516d617433d30/requests/models.py#L874) and used as the value of `r.encoding`.

`apparent_encoding` is determined by using the [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/) library to guess the encoding of the response body.

In the case of the URL in the question, the encoding is declared in the Content-Type header

```
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=gbk'
```

so `r.apparent_encoding` is not evaluated until it is explicitly accessed by executing `print(r.apparent_encoding)`.

In this particular case, chardet seems to get it wrong: the response's text attribute can be encoded with the gbk codec, but not with GB2312.

Answer (score 0):

Python `requests` use `chardet` lib to check a text whether its appearance like a charset.

You can find more in [chardet document](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/).

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` library can use the HTTP headers set on the response to figure out the response's encoding.

In your example:

```py
url = "https://item.jd.com/100000177760.html"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.headers)
```

with result:

```py
{
    "Date": "Sat, 26 Oct 2019 05:24:58 GMT",
    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=gbk",
    "Content-Length": "42964",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    #...
}
```

Where you can see `charset=gbk` in the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header.